# HTML5 change description text when clicked

Tags: javascript, css, html

I have an "a" tag in my code that upon clicking, it will toggle the visibility of an element.

in HTML I have:

```
<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility('foo');">Click here for details</a>
<div id="foo">
  <p>This is test</p>
</div>
```

Also, in my Javascript, I have:

```
function toggle_visibility(id) {
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   e.value="New Button Text";
   if(e.style.visibility == 'visible')
      e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
   else
      e.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
```

And this works fine (thanks to stackoverflow folks).

Now, what I want to do, is that when I click on "Click here for details", I would like the actual text itself change to "close the details".

"Click here for details" -> "close the details"

Also how would I change the color of the the text, so when it changes to "close the details" it becomes "red". 
How should I modify the code to do this?

Comment: try a google search, over at google.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
function toggle_visibility(el, id) {
    var e = document.getElementById(id);
    e.value = "New Button Text";
    if (e.style.visibility == 'visible')
        e.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    else
        e.style.visibility = 'visible';
    if (el.innerHTML == "Click here for details") {
        el.innerHTML = "Close the details";
        el.style.color = "red";
    }
    else {
        el.innerHTML = "Click here for details";
        el.style.color = null;
    }
}


<a href="#" onclick="toggle_visibility(this, 'foo');">Click here for details</a>
```

Comment: @Rudy01, welcome! I would appreciate it if you mark my answer as a solution)